# Drupal - page route - content profile

Tags: drupal

I can't seem to get the page route module to move to the next page, after it creates the profile page.
1. I created a route called Registration
2. Inside the route I have two pages,
a) Content Profile Editing Form 
b) Node Add form

The page route should take the user to the profile create page, and then route to the create a group node page.

Problem is after the user is directed to the content profile editing form and clicks next, it redirects back to the profile form instead of going to the next page.

Any ideas, this does not seem normal at all.

Charles

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce this, can you tell us the exact steps you followed for creating your two pages within the PageRoute module.  What are the selections you chose and set when creating your Route and the 2 pages within the Route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the help. I found the solution. I thought it might be a module or a coding change I have made so I decided to create a new drupal install and only install the modules needed.

I still had the same problem, very strange indeed. I eventually found the this article, with someone whom has had the same issues.

http://drupal.org/node/699458

The following needs to be added to the pageroute.module

```
<?php
/**
 * Submit function for all pageroute forms, except submit-like tab buttons
 * Redirect to the set target.
 */
function pageroute_page_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

  $page = &$form_state['page'];
  $route = &$form_state['storage']['route'];

 /* hack saturnino part */
  if(!empty( $page->options['neighbours']['forward']) )
  {
        drupal_redirect_form($form, $route->path.'/'.$page->options['neighbours']['forward']);
        return;
  }
  /* hack saturnino part */

  // no page access -> try redirect
  if (!$route->checkPageAccess($page->name, $form_state['target'])) {
    unset($form_state['storage']);
    $form_state['rebuild'] = FALSE;

    if ($route->options['redirect_path']) {
      drupal_redirect_form($form, pageroute_get_redirect_path($page));
      return;
    }

    drupal_not_found();
    pageroute_exit_now();
    return;
  }

  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
?>
```

thanks for your help